# Element content shows at Designtime but not Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a Menu and a TreeView defined in my MainWindow.XAML. In Designtime they show their content but not in Runtime:

[image: Designtime]
<-- Designtime

[image: Runtime]
<-- Runtime

Since the XML data is provided in the actual MainWindow.XAML file I can't see how it can be a designtime vs runtime reference error like the many image examples out there.

Let's focus on the Menu. Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData">
        <x:XData>
            <items>
                <item Name="file" />
                <item Name="edit" />
                <item Name="debug" />
            </items>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
    ...
<Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="#FFA1C4A1">
    <Menu Foreground="Blue" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="291,106,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}, XPath=items/item/@Name}" Background="#FFEF1818" />
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add  xmlns="" to your list of item.

Instead of

```
<items>
```

use

```
<items xmlns="">
```

Comment: For the curious ones : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx on the Note box on the Exemple part.
"The root node of the XML data has an xmlns attribute that sets the XML namespace to an empty string.[...]"

Comment: This worked! Both Menu and TreeView working perfectly now. And thanks for that explanatory link! Definitly a weird 'Gotcha!'. I can first accept this correct answer in 5mins Stack tells me.